# How to customize Xamarin toasts plugin for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

We're working on xamarin forms project. We've used to Toasts Plugin for Xamarin.Forms to display toasts. Mentioned below is the link of plugin - [Toasts Plugin for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin)

The plugin is working perfectly on Android but on iOS it is not allowing multi-line texts. We've tried to customize it to achieve this but of no use and limited help available. Please suggest any help or any other  plugins available for displaying toasts messages. Attached is the screen shots :-

[image: one]

[image: Two]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this issue and I just dropped this plugin and I'm gonna switch to this one [UserDialogs Plugin](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) because it offers a lot more. And we've more help. It also resolved the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify line 210 in the source

https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin/blob/master/Toasts.Forms.Plugin.iOS/MessageView.cs

from

```
        Description.DrawString(descriptionRectangle, DescriptionFont, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation, UITextAlignment.Left);
```

to

```
        Description.DrawString(descriptionRectangle, DescriptionFont, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap, UITextAlignment.Left);
```

Comment: We're using toasts plugins for this. So we've no code access for this. Can we remove plugin and use the code for this ?